# Perl Error: Argument isn't numeric in array or hash lookup

Tags: perl

I was writing a simple program to match words to a regex pattern. But I keep receiving the error above. This is my code:

```
my @words = ("Ordinary", "order", "afford", "cordford", "'ORD airport'");
foreach my $index (@words) {
    if ($words[$index] =~ m/ord/) {
        print "match\n";
    } else {print "no match\n";}
}
```

Error I received:

```
Argument "Ordinary" isn't numeric in array or hash lookup at test.pl line  6.
Argument "order" isn't numeric in array or hash lookup at test.pl line 6.
Argument "afford" isn't numeric in array or hash lookup at test.pl line 6.
Argument "cordford" isn't numeric in array or hash lookup at test.pl line 6.
Argument "'ORD airport'" isn't numeric in array or hash lookup at test.pl line 6.
no matchno matchno matchno matchno match
```

Can anyone explain to me what's causing the error and why?

Comment: http://perlmaven.com/perl-arrays

Answer (score 4):

This is the code that you show (improved a little)

```
my @words = ( 'Ordinary', 'order', 'afford', 'cordford', q{'ORD airport'} );

    for my $index ( @words ) {

        if ( $words[$index] =~ /ord/ ) {
            print "match\n";
        }
        else {
            print "no match\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This `for` loop will set `$index` to each *value* in the `@words` array. So, for instance, the first time the loop is executed `$index` will be set to `Ordinary`; the second time it will be set to `order` etc.

Naming it `$index` shows clearly that you expected it to contain all the indices for `@words`. You *can* do that, like this

```
for my $index ( 0 .. $#words ) { ... }
```

and your program will work fine if you make just that change. The output is

```
no match
match
match
match
no match
```

But you had the right idea from the start. Most often an array is just a list of values and the indices have no relevance. That applies to your case, and you can write

```
for my $word ( @words ) {

    if ( $word =~ m/ord/ ) {
        print "match\n";
    }
    else {
        print "no match\n";
    }
}
```

Or using Perl's *default variable* `$_` it can be written

```
for ( @words ) {

    if ( m/ord/ ) {
        print "match\n";
    }
    else {
        print "no match\n";
    }
}
```

or even just

```
print /ord/ ? "match\n" : "no match\n" for @words;
```

Every example above is exactly equivalent and so produces identical output

Comment: in recent perls, you can do `for my $index (keys @words)` instead of using `0..$#words`

Comment: @ysth: I'm not sure how that could help. It's a character or two longer, unfamiliar to most Perl programmers, and available only on Perls since v5.12 so there are portability issues

Comment: I hadn't realised it was possible. Now I do,  which is intriguing, but I don't think I'll use it :) I suppose it might be useful if it handles 'sparse' arrays differently?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is your `$index` will produce the elements of an array not the index values.

It should be `foreach my $index (0..$#words)` now `$index` will produce the index of an array in every iteration.

```
use strict; 
use warnings;

my @words = ("Ordinary", "order", "afford", "cordford", "'ORD airport'");

foreach my $index (0..$#words) {

    if ($words[$index] =~ m/ord/) {

       print "match\n";
    } 

    else {print "no match\n";}
 }
```

Or else. simply check the condition with `$index`.

```
use strict; 

use warnings;

my @words = ("Ordinary", "order", "afford", "cordford", "'ORD airport'");

foreach my $index (@words) {

    if ($index =~ m/ord/) {

    print "match\n";

    }

    else {print "no match\n";}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is array lookup

```
$words[$index];
```

If it was a hash it would be

```
$words{$index};
```

Arrays expect integer indexes but you're using strings that look nothing like integers.

If you are iterating over arrays in Perl you don't need the index..

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @words = ("Ordinary", "order", "afford", "cordford", "'ORD airport'");
foreach my $word (@words) {
  if($word =~ m/ord/) {      
    print "$word match\n";
  } else {
    print "$word no match\n";
  }
}
```

Note. I've used `foreach` because you see it in more language you could also use `for`

You can also try something a little bit alternative, note this won't end but it's worth studying ie

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my @words = ("Ordinary", "order", "afford", "cordford", "'ORD airport'");
my $iterator = sub {
  my $item = shift(@words);
  push(@words, $item);
  return $item;
};

while(my $item = $iterator->()) {
  print("$item\n");
}
```

I do love Perl.

Comment: `word` is an array not a hash.

Comment: I don't think you've addressed the OP's confusion here. No one mentioned hashes

Comment: The error mentioned hashes. I think it relevant that the OP realises that [] and {} are fundamentally different things in Perl.